# Visual Studio cannot find the dll boost_python39-vc142-mt-gd-x64.dll

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I want to use the boost.python to export a C++ function to python. I compiled the boost libraries(v1.78.0) for x64 architecture using :

`b2 --toolset=msvc-14.2 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage`

after including the path for the python interpreter in project-config.jam

Even after configuring visual studio with the include directory and libs directory I get an error stating :

The code execution cannot proceed because boost_python39-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78.dll was not found

python-version : 3.9

c++ compiler : msvc

msvc version: 14.2

Comment: I believe `--toolset=msvc-10.0` is wrong and is for Visual Studio 2010. It should be `--toolset=msvc-14.2`

Comment: ***The code execution cannot proceed because boost_python39-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78.dll was not found*** Does this file exist in the folder you told it to look? Did you put your dlls in a folder that is in your PATH environment variable or are the dlls in the same folder as your executable?

Comment: MS Windows uses this policy to search for required dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: The file actually exists in the $BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib directory which I have added to the Library directories in  visual studio but I am still getting the error

Comment: ***which I have added to the Library directories in visual studio but I am still getting the error*** The library settings have nothing to do with the path needed when you run your application. Windows needs to find the required dll file by one of the methods described in the Microsoft document I linked.

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to build the solution after including the libraries to the system PATH variable